# file_put_contents(): Exclusive locks are not supported for this stream, Laravel Mac OS X

Tags: php, laravel, macos, permissions

I'm using mac os x Sierra, I installed laravel and try to resolve error but could not succeed can anyone help me please, I follow the below steps.

1. change permission on storage folder.
2. cache clear.
3. Composer updated.
4. mac os x Sierra

Comment: As with most questions on SO you will get a better result from the community if you post your code

Comment: @RiggsFolly thank you it's totally fresh larave project.

<code>file_put_contents(): Exclusive locks are not supported for this stream</code>

Comment: Ok, so what were you attempting to do when you received this error

Comment: are you using vagrant?

Comment: I don't have an idea about vagrant.

Comment: get the full experience duude hahaha, no seriously, check it out: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/homestead

Comment: In resume, homestead is a virtual machine development enviroment, that runs on multiple virutal machine software like:  VirtualBox 5.2, VMWare, Parallels or Hyper-V... VirtualBox is free... it comes with everything you need already installed and configuration is minimal... Homestead is packaged on a Vagrant box that runs on this machines.

Comment: I understand but in my windows system it's working fine but now not in mac

Comment: Edit your question, add your code, add your exact error.

Answer (score 8):

Change the line of code Filesystem.php to

from this

```
return file_put_contents($path, $contents, $lock ? LOCK_EX : 0);
```

to

```
return file_put_contents($path, $contents, $lock ? LOCK_SH : 0);
```

Comment: where is that filesystem.php located??

Comment: yourProject/config/filesystem.php

Answer (score 7):

I solved this problem on my MacBook Pro (running Mojave) by going to my LaravelProject's folder first. Then I navigated to LaravelProject's `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Filesystem\Filesystem.php` and searched and modified

`return file_put_contents($path, $contents, $lock ? LOCK_EX : 0);`

to

`return file_put_contents($path, $contents, $lock ? LOCK_SH : 0);`.

If any kind of confirmation is asked while modifying this file, confirm it.

Comment: This is not a great idea. When updating to a new version of the framework the changes will be reverted. You should never change code in vendor packages.